# Matching constness of function argument for return type with concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

C++ containers do not hold const elements, e.g. you have `const std::vector<int>`, not `std::vector<const int>`.
This is a bit unfortunate when I am trying to adjust type of return value of a function based of if passed container was const or not.

Here is motivating example, please do not focus too much on algorithm or use of boost, I only use it since C++ optional has not support for references.

This code [appears to work](https://godbolt.org/z/hcd4vqoGY), but code looks quite ugly, so I wonder if concepts give us a way to write this in a nicer way.
I presume not since basically concepts are just predicates, but I am hoping for something nice, in particular return type is quite spammy.

```
    template<typename C>
    using match_const = std::conditional_t< std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<C>>,
            const typename std::remove_reference_t<C>::value_type,
            typename std::remove_reference_t<C>::value_type>;

    // no constraints
    auto ofind(auto& container, const auto& value) -> boost::optional<match_const<decltype(container)>&> {
        if (auto it = std::ranges::find(container, value); it!=container.end()){
            return *it;
        }
        return boost::none;
    }
    
    // dummy concept
    template<typename C>
    concept Container  = requires (C c){
        {c.begin()};
        {c.end()};
        {c.size()} -> std::same_as<size_t>;
    };

    // constraints version
    auto ofind2(Container auto& container, const auto& value) ->boost::optional<match_const<decltype(container)>&>{
        if (auto it = std::ranges::find(container, value); it!=container.end()){
            return *it;
        }
        return boost::none;
    }
```

If my question is too vague here is my idealized version:

```
boost::optional<Container::real_reference> ofind(Container auto& container, const auto& value)
```

Where Container::real_reference is something that matches the constness unlike reference typedef in vector, for example consider this:

```
using CVI = const std::vector<int>;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<int&, CVI::reference>); // compiles
```

note: I know I should make second argument also more constrained, but for simplicity I left it as just `const auto&`.

Comment: Don't you just need `boost::optional<decltype(*container.begin())&>`?

Comment: You don't have to apologize for using `boost::optional`, it's not your fault that `std::optional` is just arbitrarily lacking in functionality.

Comment: "_C++ containers do not hold const elements_" - They will if you declare them like in your example: `std::vector<const int>`.

Comment: @Barry I was  just trying to preempt people getting focused on that, since my issue is basically unrelated to boost::optional, it could have been (*gasp*) a raw pointer that is const or not. :)

Comment: @NathanOliver I consider that ugly, but yes that also works, and is probably than my code.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Except `vector<T const>` isn't a thing.

Comment: @Barry That should depend on what operations you perform on the `vector<T const>`, shouldn't it? I don't see a rule saying `T` can't be `const`, but [g++ rejects it while clang++ accepts it](https://godbolt.org/z/ohEn1EP41) so you may be correct.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it does not work with any compiler... https://godbolt.org/z/cd3nK3qE5

Comment: @TedLyngmo also suprisingly msvc gives best error https://godbolt.org/z/bY8E375Y6

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl The `push_back` is cheating :-) The MSVC error does indeed imply that it's forbidden though. "_The C++ Standard forbids containers of `const` elements because `allocator<const T>` is ill-formed_" - I did read [`std::allocator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) but I didn't find support for it there. Perhaps it's in the standard somewhere. Edit: `[tab:allocator.req.var]` mentions "_`T`, `U`, `C`_" as being "_any cv-unqualified object type_" which supports what you both are saying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ranges already gives us a way to get the correct reference type of any range:

```cpp
std::ranges::range_reference_t<R>
```

If `R` is `vector<int>`, that's `int&`. If `R` is `vector<int> const`, that's `int const&`. If `R` is `span<int> const`, that's... still `int&` because `span` is shallow-const (which is something your trait gets wrong, because it assumes that everything is deep-const).

This trait isn't magical, all it does is give you precisely the type that the underlying iterator dereferences to: `decltype(*ranges::begin(r))`.

With that, your `find` can look like:

```cpp
template <range R>
auto ofind(R& container, const auto& value) -> boost::optional<range_reference_t<R>>;
```

Note that if you actually need to use the *types* of your parameters, using abbreviated function template syntax is not actually going to be all that abbreviated due to having to write `decltype`, so you can just... use normal function template syntax.

Comment: Just to be 100% clear, there is no way for me to put a typedef/using inside a concept, like Container::real_reference?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl No.